How can I set require() to dynamically update with an image path in React?
I have an image on my About page of a react app which i'd like the image to change to a new image every 5secs. I have set up my hooks and my aboutImg state is initially set to require('./img/rope.jpg') which renders the image. But when I try to dynamically update this I get the following error for each path way I try to dynamically add:
Cannot find module './img/Horseback-riding.jpg'
    at webpackEmptyContext (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:64374:10)
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:2974:68

My code is:
function About() {

    const tempImg =['./img/Horseback-riding.jpg','./img/Snowshoeing.jpg','./img/yoga3.3.jpg','./img/rope.jpg']

    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
    const [aboutImg, setAboutImg] = useState(require('./img/rope.jpg'))

    useEffect(() => {
        //Implementing the setInterval method
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            counter === 3 ? setCounter(0) : setCounter(counter + 1);
            setAboutImg(require(tempImg[counter]))
            // setCount(count + 1);
        }, 5000); // every 5secs it changes

        //Clearing the interval
        return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }, [counter]);

    return (
       <img src={aboutImg}/>
    )

}

export default About;


The reason i was trying to use require is because i have 90+ images that i want to cycle through
I have consoled.logged aboutImg and can see it's showing the correct string but when i add the variable into the require() it causes this error

As recommended by @Siamak, i managed to implement require.context() to solve the issue, so here is the final code
function About() {
    
    const imgFolder = require.context('./img/', false)
    
    const tempImg =['./img/Horseback-riding.jpg','./img/Snowshoeing.jpg','./img/yoga3.3.jpg','./img/rope.jpg']

    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
    const [aboutImg, setAboutImg] = useState(require('./img/rope.jpg'))

    //make the image change every 5secs
    useEffect(() => {
        //Implementing the setInterval method
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            counter === 3 ? setCounter(0) : setCounter(counter + 1);
            setAboutImg( require(`${tempImg[counter]}`))
            console.log(`aboutImg = ${aboutImg}`)
        }, 5000); // every 5secs it changes

        //Clearing the interval
        return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }, [counter]);

        return (
           <img src={aboutImg}/>
        )
    
 }
    
 export default About;

